# Translation for threshold (figuratively)

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request

How would I translate an administrative threshold into German?
This is in software where there is a threshold for the amount of (excess) hours someone works without overpay, but once the threshold has been reached, he/she will get paid extra.

- Schwelle?
- Grenze?

Maybe it helps if we consider *limit* instead of *threshold*...

Edit:
Here is the entire context:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to emphasise "limit" or "threshold"?

Comment: @PiedPiper *threshold*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Schwelle** is the best solution here. It implies a transition from one state to another. You have a transition from unpaid to paid overtime.
**Schwellenwert** or **Schwellwert** would be another possibility if you wanted to emphasise the **value** at the transition rather than the transition itself.

**Grenze** (or **Grenzwert**) is not as good because it implies a limit. However it might be useful if there was an upper limit on how many overtime hours could be paid

Comment: I'm going for these two, whichever one applies. Using *Schwellwert* instead if *Schwellenwert* though.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer

> Schwellwert

or

> Grenzwert

as a translation for it. 
This also emphasizes the fact that it is a value that is being measured, instead of a vague criterium or a notion.

And in contrast to limit, it simply demarks a value after which you *transition* into a different phase/context/state, while limit seems to be the very *end* of a scale.

Depending on context other translations might also be applicable:

> Wendepunkt, Entscheidungskriterium, ...

Comment: But limit **is** Grenze or Grenzwert.

Comment: And OP asks explicitly which word fits better in this case - Schwelle or Grenze (or Schwellwert or Grenzwert).

Comment: I think that Schwelle(nwert) is best because it does not mean something will stop (als Grenze/Limit at least hints) but rather some parameters will change beyond that Schwelle.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: I agree. Scaling from Schwelle(nwert) over Grenzwert to Limit, the emphasis shifts from transitioning between two states to the limit of a domain.

Comment: @IQV: He asked which words fit and gave two own suggestions. I told him his suggestions were fine, but slightly modified them and gave reason for it. I also tried to argue why i would not use limit (or its translations).

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather prefer

> Grenze

to use here in this case of worker's overtime.

As synonym I would also consider

> Limit

It might sound more denglish, just in my opinion it is not uncommon to use it. Maybe because it sounds softer due to "L" instead of "G"

Like others stated, it might sound like limiting something. Putting it into the context of payed overtime, it does: it limits the time unpaid. And that is not fluid, you need to change a contract or (external) laws instead of just a parameter/ configuration.

e.g.:

> Die Grenze des Landes ist erreicht. -> despite that the countryside goes on, so it is no "Schwellwert" and "defined by contract".
>
> Die tägliche Arbeitszeit ist per Gesetz begrenzt. -> it does not limit to do more or to ask for more.

I see more the context of "if the limit is reached, we need to take action". Considering this, I assume something like this for last column

```
Grenze [*] beachten
Grenze [*] ignorieren
Grenze für tägliche Überstunden
(no idea)
(no idea) +falls Grenze überschritten
Wöchentliche Grenze
```

[*] = for calculation

<sub>(As you did not ask for a full german translation, I did not ask for a english translation I could put the verbs into context, so I might miss the point)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Schwelle, Grenze, Limite: all are useful here.

In context with work overtime  **das Limit** or die Limite fits best!